# Cannot use object linking and embedding

Tags: excel, windows, powershell-4.0, dcom

I've a Powershell script to set up user identity of a 32bits DCOM application (Excel 32bits). To do that, I've used a sample of Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7  that I've compiled DComPerm.exe.

```
New-Item -Path "$RegPath" -Name "$AppID" -Value "Microsoft Excel Application"
Dcomp.exe -runas "$appId" $DomainUser $Password
```

Everything seems good, just that I expect Excel to throw this exception when I open it up:

“Cannot use object linking and embedding”

[image]

This happen only if I manually type mmc comexp.msc /32 and then browse the component service console till I click on DCOM Config.

(Which is normal I'm running 32-bit Excel application on a 64-bit Windows machine)

i don’t know how to script that last step.